# Prove the variance of Hansen-Hurwitz estimator

Tags: statistics, summation, sampling-theory

The Hansen-Hurwitz estimator of the population total, $Y=\sum_{I=1}^{N} Y_{I}$, is given as:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{y}_{\mathrm{HH}}^{\prime}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{y_{i}}{p_{i}}
\end{equation}
Then its variance can be expressed variously as:
\begin{align}
V\left(y_{\mathrm{HH}}^{\prime}\right) &=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{I=1}^{N} \frac{Y_{I}^{2}}{P_{I}}-Y^{2}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{I=1}^{N} P_{I}\left(\frac{Y_I}{P_{I}}-Y\right)^{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2 n} \sum_{I}^{N} \sum_{J =1,  \neq I}^{N}P_IP_J\left(\frac{Y_I}{P_{I}}-\frac{Y_J}{P_{J}}\right)^{2}
\end{align}
The first two lines of this equation are easily to prove, **could somebody
elaborate the last line**?

Notations: 
$y_i$: the value taken by $i$-th sample unit. 
$Y_I$: the value of $I$-th population unit. 
$p_i$: the probability of that a given sample unit will be selected. 
$P_I$: the probability of that a given population unit will be selected. 
$N$: number of units in the population. 
$n$: number of units in the sample.

Comment: For $I\ne J$, you have $\sum_{I=1}^{N} \sum_{J=1}^{N}P_IP_J\left(\frac{Y_I}{P_{I}}-\frac{Y_J}{P_{J}}\right)^{2}=2\left(\sum_{I=1}^N \frac{Y_I^2}{P_I}-Y^2\right)$ simply by expanding the left hand side.